# Check for value in a csv string

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to check for a value in a given list of csv values. I have the following code that in theory should work. But for some reason its not. Not sure what i am doing wrong here. Can someone please help.

```
$string = "5,9,10,13";

 function checkDay($day, $list){

        if (strpos($list, $day) !== FALSE) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }       
    }

for ($x=0; $x<=15; $x++) {
  if(checkDay($x, $string)){
    echo "There is an event on " . $x . "<br>";  
  }else{
    echo "There is NO event on " . $x . "<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: If you used the `explode` function on your list, you'd get an array and putting that through `foreach` would be a lot simpler than what you have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code won't work like you think. A day of `3` will return true if `131` is in your list of dates.

A better way to do this is to put your dates into an array and check to see if your day is a value in that array. That if/else statement is also unnecessary.

```
$string = "5,9,10,13";

function checkDay($day, $list){
    $dates = explode(',', $list);
    return in_array($day, $dates);      
}

for ($x=0; $x<=15; $x++) {
  if(checkDay($x, $string)){
    echo "There is an event on " . $x . "<br>";  
  }else{
    echo "There is NO event on " . $x . "<br>";
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/194215)

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = "5,9,10,13";
$days = explode(',', $string);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 15; ++$x) {
    if (in_array($x, $days)) {
        echo "There is an event on $x.<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "There is NO event on $x.<br/>";
    }
}
```

[Example (uses \n instead of <br/>)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f1fcb59cfdec519833e9ef689d47792293c8554)

Comment: Creepy similar answers are creepy. (edit: referring to John's answer)

Comment: Your answer explode a single time, while John's code will do it 15 times. To me it's not similar, it's better. ;)

Comment: Actually it'll run `explode` 16 times, but you're right; it uses less resources.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutly wants it to work that way (In the case where you were just giving an example that wouldn't work with explode), you could just typecast your `$x` to string when you call your function :

```
if(checkDay((string) $x, $string)){
```